# UIImageView Touch Event

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch

I want to call my button click event while touching the uiimageview named as(image1).Imageview placed in uiview(view1).

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

 myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(alphabutt:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }


-(IBAction)alphabutt:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"alphabutt!");


 if(i==1)
 {
  NSLog(@"i==1");
  [image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appleimg.jpg"]];
  [view1 addSubview:image1];  
  transition1 = [CATransition animation];

  transition1.duration = 0.75;

  transition1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

  transition1.type=kCATransitionReveal;
  transition1.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
  transitioning = YES;
  transition1.delegate = self;
  [image1.layer addAnimation:transition1 forKey:nil];  
 }
 if(i==2)
 {
  NSLog(@"i==2");
  [image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boatimg.jpg"]];
  [view1 addSubview:image1];  
  transition2 = [CATransition animation];

  transition2.duration = 0.75;

  transition2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

  transition2.type=kCATransitionFade;
  transition2.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
  transitioning = YES;
  transition2.delegate = self;
  [image1.layer addAnimation:transition2 forKey:nil];

  i=0;
 }
i++;

}
```

The above is my code while clicking the button the buttonclicked event is called.Inside buttonclick event the timer is working to call the alphabutt(Button click event)with the time interval of 2.0.alphabutt is called with every 2.0.I want to do this animation when i'm touch the uiimageview(image1) then only it calls the button click event (alphabutt).
how can I write the touch event for imageview...

Please explain briefly with some code to perform uiimageview touch event...

Comment: Please reply me as soon as possible...

Comment: Please, ALWAYS format your code. Your question is confusing about imageview touch and button touch (what do you want to ask here?)

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the code....In my code inside buttonclicked event NSTimer(myTimer)is used to call the another button click event(alphabutt)with the time intervel of 2.0.Instead of timer i want to call the alphabutt(button click event)by uiimageview(image1)touchevent .How can i do this...Plz help me...

Comment: In my code only one uiview(view1)and inside that view uiimageview(image1)is placed...Please reply me as soon as possible...Thank you   Renya

Comment: The answer of Vivek Sehrawat at [Click Event on UIImageView programmatically in ios][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120476/click-event-on-uiimageview-programmatically-in-ios/17120537#17120537 
is useful for you :D

Comment: Check this **simple answer** [http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007)

Answer (score 63):

you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to the `UIImageView` via `addGestureRecognizer`

snippets:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerTapped:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[iv addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[iv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

and

```
- (void)bannerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"%@", [gestureRecognizer view]);
}
```

Answer (score 58):

Make your image view user interaction enabled in the xib (or through the code if you are adding it programmatically) and use the UIResponder methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc to detect the touch on the image view:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == yourImageView)
    {
            //add your code for image touch here 
    }

}
```

Comment: hi...My application is based on tabbar application.I'm giving all the code for touch events inside the myAppAppDelegate.m...It's not working what should i do in my application.Please explain briefly...I'm waiting Please reply soon...Thank you...

Comment: you dont have to handle touches in app delegate... implement the touch methods in your view controller which contains the image...

Comment: and make sure your image view is 'userInteractionEnabled'

Comment: Check  **Swift version** [http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007)

Answer (score 15):

Here I show you two possibilities for achieving that in **Swift**:

**First Possibility**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myUIImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // You can also manually set it through IB 
        // selecting the UIImageView in the storyboard
        // and checking "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox 
        // in the Attributes Inspector panel.
        self.myUIImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    // You can choose to use one of the UIResponder methods:
    // touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc, in order to detect the touch
    // on the UIImageView.
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       let touch: UITouch? = touches.first
       if touch?.view == myUIImageView {
          println("myUIImageView has been tapped by the user.")
       }
       super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

**Second Possibility**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myUIImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "myUIImageViewTapped:")
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 // Initialized to 1 by default
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1 // Initialized to 1 by default
        self.myUIImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        self.myUIImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func myUIImageViewTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
            println("myUIImageView has been tapped by the user.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also drag and drop a `UIButton` object over the `UIImageView`. Then in the storyboard editor, just make the `UIButton` of `Custom` type, rendering the `UIButton` invisible. Then handle the `click` event just like you would for any button.

Comment: Check  **Swift version** [http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007)