# iPhone - Touch event is not received by UIImageView while animating using CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, quartz-2d

i Have a UIImageview object moving along a path and i have use CABasic animation and BezierCure to move the object along the path, Now the problem is if i touch the moving object the touch event is not recognized by the UIImageView but the touch event is received by main view. can anybody help me to solve this problem?
Below is my code

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if (![touch.view isEqual: beaconPose1]) {
    return;
}
[touch.view.layer removeAllAnimations];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

  CGRect frame = touch.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = location.x;
frame.origin.y  = location.y;
///frame.origin.x += xDisplacement;
//frame.origin.y += yDisplacement;
touch.view.frame = frame;
```

-- Code where User Interaction is enabled

```
[beaconPose1 setUserInteractionEnabled:true];

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
pathAnimation.path = beaconPose3Path.CGPath;
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;

CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = pathAnimation.duration;
fullRotation.repeatCount = pathAnimation.duration/fullRotation.duration;
[beaconPose1.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
[beaconPose1.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"movingAnimation"];
```

Comment: I am Not Sure but This Might Help you


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775577/uiimageview-touch-event

Comment: I implemented same logic, bot UIImageView is not receiving the touch events :(

Comment: plz post the code you are using that helps for checking...

Comment: @pete try to change this `self.view` with `touch.view`.

Comment: You need to "enableUserInteraction" where you set the animation. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes i have enabled User interaction, but still it is not working

Comment: @Kamarshad if (![touch.view isEqual: beaconPose1])  condition itself is not satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this,

The object under `CAKeyframeAnimation` or `CABasicAnimation` will not respond to touch event, instead what we can do is calculate if the location of the touch is withing the area of the object using Pythagorus theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the currently accepted answer is wrong:

When the user puts his finger on the screen, all the views are hit-tested with the touch position. However, when hit-testing them, the view's `frame` is requested. This is, however, linked to the `modelLayer`s frame, which is the end point of your animation.

What you would want is hit-testing the `presentationLayer`, but I guess this is not possible.