# Click Event on UIImageView programmatically in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitouch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am displaying a image from code here is the code

```
UIImageView *preArrowImage =[[UIImageView alloc]init ];
preArrowImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowprev.png"];
preArrowImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, 10, 30);
[self.view addSubview:preArrowImage];
```

I want to handle the touch event on the preArrowImage programmatically.

Comment: This may be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out-in-ios

Comment: Check this answer will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328885/3177007)

Answer (score 260, accepted):

**SWIFT 5**

```
let preArrowImage : UIImageView // also give it frame
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetected))
preArrowImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
preArrowImage.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

//Action
 func tapDetected() {
    print("Imageview Clicked")
}
```

**Objective-c**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[preArrowImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[preArrowImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
 
-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
  }
```

Comment: for Swift 2 you should replace `Selector("tapDetected")` with: `"tapDetected:"`

Comment: By default singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1, Happy Coding Thanks

Comment: 'let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NavigationViewController.tapDetectedImage))'

Answer (score 18):

Simply add a `UITapGesture` on the image but remember to make its **UserInteraction Enabled**.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
    action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [preArrowImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [preArrowImage setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [preArrowImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

Now in Swift!

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapDetected"))
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

preArrowImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
preArrowImage.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)


//Action
func tapDetected() {
    println("Single Tap on imageview")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

On **UIImageView enable UserInterAction**

```
 override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        if let touch = touches.first {
            if touch.view == self.imgVwPostPreview { //image View property

                //Do your actions
                //self.delegate?.didClickOnCellImageView(indexPath: self.cellIndexPath!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using story board with view in view controller.** 
*[image: view may be ImageView, UIView, UILabel, TextField or other controller]*

After selecting one of the gesture recognizer drag it to your controller. 
Now it will display in "Document outline" and header of view controller xib.

[image: Gesture icon in document out line and xib]

Drag gesture to UILable
[image: Drag gesture to UILable]

[image: Manually create (IBAction)method in header file]

create IBAction method in header file

Now drag it from handler to gesture icon in xib 
[image: Link it with gesture icon]

Answer (score 1):

**Xamarin.iOS**

```
UIImageView preArrowImage; // also give it frame
var singleTap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(TapDetected);
singleTap.ShouldReceiveTouch -= TapGesture_ShouldReceiveTouch;
singleTap.ShouldReceiveTouch += TapGesture_ShouldReceiveTouch;
preArrowImage.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
preArrowImage.AddGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

bool TapGesture_ShouldReceiveTouch(UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
{
    return true;
}

void TapDetected(UITapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("Imageview Clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your UIImageView is an IBOutlet which you get from a Storyboard or Nib, you could add a UIGestureRecognizer to the image view, enable user interaction and connect a IBAction to the gesture recognizer.

For more info check my answer on this question: [How to you make a UIImageView on the storyboard clickable (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202882/how-to-you-make-a-uiimageview-on-the-storyboard-clickable-swift/44053515#44053515)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: Cheat.

I mean, think laterally.

Set up your UIImage how you want, cropped, aspect fit, whatever.

Overlay this with a UIView (equal dimensions, position etc.)

Set the background to clearcolour, and the class to UIControl.

Point the touch up inside event to your handler, and voila.

Comment: Even easier than an UIView: Use a button and delete the text. ;)